# How to resize my 2d game to fit the screen?

Tags: java, graphics, resolution

[image]

I am currently making a 2D game using Java (Java 2D). I want to make my game resizable. If you play any game on an emulator (e.g. legend of Zelda in fceux emulator) in full screen mode, you'll see that the 8-bit or 16-bit game re-sizes to fit the screen size. How can I implement the same thing in my game programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using the standard Java 2D API, not OpenGL.

In that case, you render your graphics to a buffer image first. Then, to render that image to the screen, you can either use a [Graphics.drawImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage%28java.awt.Image,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) call that allows resizing your buffered image:

```
public abstract boolean drawImage(Image img,        // the buffer image
                int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, // 0, 0, screen.w, screen.h
                int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, // 0, 0, image.w, image.h
                ImageObserver observer)             // null is fine
```

or, if you want to have more control over the scaling algorithm, you can first convert the image to a second buffered image using the [following method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29) of the `Image` class:

```
public Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)
```

Here, the parameter `hints` is one of

```
Image.SCALE_DEFAULT
Image.SCALE_FAST
Image.SCALE_SMOOTH
Image.SCALE_REPLICATE
Image.SCALE_AREA_AVERAGING
```

See the [API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#field_summary) for details. For bigger games, you might want to keep an eye on performance doing these rescales, but for typical 8-bit resolutions you should probably be fine.

Comment: yay...nice answer. "getscaledinstance" is working awesome.

Comment: i **REALLY** want to urge you to not use getScaledInstance! read this article about the perils of ScaledInstance https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/04/03/perils-of-image-getscaledinstance.html

Comment: ScaledInstance has been discussed on StackOverflow for many times.. so condsider using drawImage instead!